# Wpf Combobox Equals method illogical behavior

Tags: wpf, combobox, equals

I have some academic question here about `Combobox` control. So I have this control and have `ComboboxItem` class which instances are items in combobox. I overrided `Equals` method in `ComboboxItem` class and try to observe what exactly occuring in it. And I see unexpected (as I think) behavior. Look.

Code-behind:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("N = {Name}")]
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    // It is not very correctly written but it is not a problem
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        var cmb = obj as ComboboxItem;
        if (cmb == null)
            return false;

        if (Id.Equals(cmb.Id))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow
{
    private ComboboxItem _selectedItem;
    private List<ComboboxItem> _source;

    public ComboboxItem SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value; 
        }
    }

    public List<ComboboxItem> Source    
    {
        get { return _source; }
        set { _source = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        _source = new List<ComboboxItem>
        {
            new ComboboxItem
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Name11"
            },
            new ComboboxItem
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Name22"
            },
            new ComboboxItem
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "Name33"
            },
        };

        // Name must be different from "Name33" for better observing
        _selectedItem = new ComboboxItem {Id = 3, Name = "AlmostName33"};
    }       
}
```

XAML:

```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
  </ComboBox>
```

Pretty simle as you can see. It really works, i.e. item with `Name`= "AlmostName33" will be set as `SelectedItem` in `Combobox`.

---

Issue is in the `Equals` method and in quantity of its invokes. I thought `Equals` will be invoked only 3 (three!) times to compare `SelectedItem` with every item in `Combobox`. But it does invokes 6 (six!) times and obj parameter very unexpected for me. In details:

1) 
this = "Name11"
obj = "Name11"  ---------- what is this? Why not "AlmostName33"?

2)
this = "Name11"
obj = "AlmostName33"

3)
this = "Name22"
obj = "AlmostName33"

4)
this = "Name22"
obj = "AlmostName33"

5)
this = "Name33"
obj = "AlmostName33"

6)
this = "Name33"
obj = "AlmostName33"

Can anyone clearly explain me why I have six invokes and why obj = "Name11" in the first invoke?

---

**Update**

```
_source = new List<ComboboxItem>
{
    new ComboboxItem
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Name11"
    },
    new ComboboxItem
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Name22"
    }

};

var item = new ComboboxItem
{
    Id = 3,
    Name = "Name33"
},

_source.Add(item);
_selectedItem = item;
```

Comment: +1 for an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

After testing your code, I cannot verify your results at all. My results are partially as expected and as follows:

1) this = "Name11" obj = "Name11" - this is because "Name11" was originally selected.

2) this = "Name11" obj = "AlmostName33" - this is because "AlmostName33" is being selected.

3) this = "Name22" obj = "AlmostName33" - this is because "AlmostName33" is being selected.

4) this = "Name33" obj = "AlmostName33" - this is because "AlmostName33" is being selected.

5) this = "Name11" obj = "AlmostName33"

6) this = "Name22" obj = "AlmostName33"

7) this = "Name33" obj = "AlmostName33"

8) this = "Name11" obj = "AlmostName33"

9) this = "Name22" obj = "AlmostName33"

10) this = "Name33" obj = "AlmostName33"

So basically, the first call to the `Equals` method was because the `"Name11"` value was initially selected... you can verify this by putting a breakpoint in the method and then stepping over the code until it comes out of the method and returns to the `SelectedItem` property getter.

The next three calls are the expected calls, where the Framework is comparing the potential selected value with each item in the collection. Then something goes wrong. I suspect that it has something to do with either the fact that you have not implemented your `Equals` method correctly, or you are trying to select an item that is not in the collection.

Comment: I can confirm that `Selector` (and it's derivatives such as `ComboBox`) does NOT support having a `SelectedItem` that's not part of the `Items` collection. Unexpected behavior is to be expected (no pun intended) if that is the case.

Comment: Wow! You have even 10 invokes. It is even more strange then my results. If talk about first call, I check as you said `SelectedItem` of `ComboboxItem` and its value equals `"AlmostName33"`, not `"Name11"`. But I think it is correct, I set it value by myself in constructor. Therefore, question about first invoke with obj = `"Name"` remains opened. Furthermore, I change `Combobox` initialization (see update) and `SelectedItem` is part of the `Items` collection now. And again I have the same results :)